# Menu Dropdown Showing in wrong spot

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation

I have blown 5 hours already on this.

There is a second menu.  When you hover over an item, the dropdown is in the wrong place.

Please help.

Here is the CSS.

```
/* MY RIGGING MENU*/
#menu-rigging-menu {
border-bottom: 5px solid #EDEDED;
display:inline-block !important;  
text-align:left;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
}
#menu-rigging-menu ul {
margin:0;
text-indent:0;
}

#menu-rigging-menu a li, #menu-rigging-menu a  {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
background: #ededed;
margin: 0px 10px; 
}
#menu-rigging-menu li a {
color: #000000;
line-height: 38px;
padding: 0 10px;
}

#menu-rigging-menu li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
#menu-rigging-menu li {
margin: 0 2.85714rem 0 0;
position: relative;
list-style: none outside none;
}
#menu-rigging-menu li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 43px;
z-index: 1;
margin:0;
padding:0;
 }
 #menu-rigging-menu li ul ul {
left: 100%;
  top: 0;
 }

#menu-rigging-menu li:hover > ul {
border-left: 0 none;
display: inline-block;
 }

 #menu-rigging-menu ul li a {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFEFEF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDED;
display: block;
font-size: 0.785714rem;
line-height: 2.18182;
padding: 0.571429rem 0.714286rem;
white-space: normal;
width: 12.8571rem;
/*  position:relative;  */
}


#menu-rigging-menu li ul li a:hover {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E3E3E3;
  color: #444444;
}
#menu-rigging-menu .current-menu-item > a, #menu-rigging-menu .current-
menu-ancestor      >     a, #menu-rigging-menu .current_page_item > a, #menu-
rigging-menu .current_page_ancestor > a {
color: #636363;
font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: a response to the link with a link [Pure CSS Drop Down](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- It seems your menu items are not interpreted by the CSS parser to be horisontally aligned side-by-side. Normally list items are shown below each other. Whatever the reason, make them float left to fix that the submenus are positioned relative to the parent menu items.

```
#menu-rigging-menu > li {
    float: left;
}
```

2- You should specify the `left` positional property of the submenus so they are correctly left-aligned with the parent menu item.

```
#menu-rigging-menu > li ul {
    left: 0;
}
```

That should put you on the right track.

**Update:)**

To persist the hover effect also on the submenu try changing the CSS code block that has the following selector **#menu-rigging-menu li:hover > ul** to this:

```
#menu-rigging-menu li:hover > ul,
#menu-rigging-menu li > ul:hover {
    border-left: 0 none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Yes, now we are closer, but now I cannot hover over the menu, it just vanishes.

Comment: @DavidFogel I see. Please try my updated answer. Oh and I guess you realize I cannot do all the work for you beyond answering your question.

Comment: thanks. I fixed that issue.  The height was too high so it wasnt touching.

Comment: No problem:) please mark my answer if it answered your question.